# Is multiplying really faster than dividing?

Tags: python, optimization

I've already asked something similar, but I just cant get my head around it.

I've heard many times that multiplying is indeed faster than dividing so I took it for granted.
I am trying to see it by myself but in my program division ends up the fastest, what am I doing wrong?

I've been told that it could be the compiler/interpreter optimizing so I've tried in C++, Python and Java, shows pretty much the same results on all.

```
import timeit

counter = 0
reverse_counter = 0

for i in range(0,100):
    n = timeit.timeit('500.0 * 0.25', number=10000)
    m = timeit.timeit('500.0 / 4.0', number=10000)

    if n < m:
        counter = counter + 1
    elif n != m:
        reverse_counter = reverse_counter + 1

print(counter)
print(reverse_counter)

37
48
----
42
49
```

Comment: It may be possible for it to realize that `* 0.25` is the same thing as `/ 4` and optimize accordingly. I'll note though that when I test this, whichever test I run first is considered slower, for whatever reason.

Comment: Don't use 4, that's 2^2 - binary's piece of cake - use some other number.

Comment: That's what I thought at the start, but usually there are faster division results in all the three languages I used, maybe it optimizes divisions further than multiplications?

Comment: I've tried it with 2, 3, 4 and 5, only 2 seems to be a winner for multiplication.

Comment: Dude, this is *programming*, tell me what's happening for the first trillion positive natural numbers...

Comment: In Java the divisors and nominators were randomized (between 0-10000) if that's enough ^^, still the same issue.

Comment: You're not timing multiplication *or* division. They both get optimized out. You're timing the timing loop.

Comment: And even if they weren't optimized out, they're both like 100-1000x times faster than all the interpreter overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that python code is byte-compiled. When you use constants, arithmetic on those constants can be pre-computed, so that when the bytecode is executed, a constant is merely loaded:

```
In [234]: import dis

In [235]: dis.dis('500.0 * 0.25')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (125.0)
              2 RETURN_VALUE

In [236]: dis.dis('500.0 / 4.0')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               2 (125.0)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

The bytecode is identical!
This explains why you are not seeing multiplication as faster than division when timing with

```
n = timeit.timeit('500.0 * 0.25', number=10000)
m = timeit.timeit('500.0 / 4.0', number=10000)
```

---

Instead, let's write setup code which performs multiplications and division on random numbers:

```
import timeit
counter = 0
reverse_counter = 0


setup = '''\
import random
x = [random.random() for i in range(10**6)]
y = [random.random() for i in range(10**6)]
'''    
multiply = '[xi*yi for xi, yi in zip(x, y)]'
divide = '[xi/yi for xi, yi in zip(x, y)]'

N = 100
for i in range(0, N):
    n = timeit.timeit(multiply, setup=setup, number=3)
    m = timeit.timeit(divide, setup=setup, number=3)    

    if n < m:
        counter = counter + 1

print('multiply is faster {:.2%} of the time'.format(counter/N))
```

yields on my machine:

```
multiply is faster 99.00% of the time
```